# Neo4J 2.0.2 server refuses to start under Java 8, Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: java, macos, neo4j

I have a fresh download of Neo4J Community 2.0.2 on MacOS X 10.9.2 using Java 8 (1.8.0-b132). The server will not start, writing the following to the log:

```
14:59:54.471 [main] WARN  org.neo4j.kernel.info.JvmChecker - You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
```

I've seen reports on SO saying that Neo4J 2.0.x runs fine under Java 8: what incantation am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the process show as running when you use ps -ef | grep neo?

Answer (score 1):

Entirely user error here: the server is of course starting just fine --- I took the warning to be more than it was. Everything is running as I would expect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me too, just tried it because of your post?

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
```

This is just a warning the server should continue to start.

Can you run `bin/neo4j console` to see the real error? Or check `data/graph.db/messages.log` for more details.